# npm install-test : Missing script: "test" | npm package commands not found

Tags: node.js, npm, command-line, expo

I am receiving a: *Missing script: "test"* when running *'npm install-test'*

```
1. Download node via the Mac installer (new MacBook macOS Monterey 12.1)

2. Install expo cli 

3. Run expo start
```

Weird things happen when I do this:

•npm expo —version works and returns the right version

•npm ls  : Displays that packages are installed

•npm install-test and install-ci-test returns the following error:

```
npm ERR! Missing script: "test"
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
npm ERR!   npm run

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/main/.npm/_logs/2022-02-21T14_13_35_935Z-debug-0.log
```

**Debug Log:**

```
0 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'install-test' ]
1 info using npm@8.3.1
2 info using node@v16.14.0
3 timing npm:load:whichnode Completed in 0ms
4 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 1ms
5 timing config:load:file:/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/npmrc Completed in 0ms
6 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 0ms
7 timing config:load:cli Completed in 1ms
8 timing config:load:env Completed in 0ms
9 timing config:load:project Completed in 0ms
10 timing config:load:file:/Users/main/.npmrc Completed in 1ms
11 timing config:load:user Completed in 1ms
12 timing config:load:file:/Users/main/.npm-global/etc/npmrc Completed in 1ms
13 timing config:load:global Completed in 1ms
14 timing config:load:validate Completed in 0ms
15 timing config:load:credentials Completed in 1ms
16 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 0ms
17 timing config:load Completed in 5ms
18 timing npm:load:configload Completed in 5ms
19 timing npm:load:setTitle Completed in 5ms
20 timing config:load:flatten Completed in 2ms
21 timing npm:load:display Completed in 2ms
22 verbose logfile /Users/main/.npm/_logs/2022-02-21T14_13_35_935Z-debug-0.log
23 timing npm:load:logFile Completed in 2ms
24 timing npm:load:timers Completed in 0ms
25 timing npm:load:configScope Completed in 0ms
26 timing npm:load Completed in 14ms
27 timing arborist:ctor Completed in 0ms
28 silly logfile start cleaning logs, removing 2 files
29 timing idealTree:init Completed in 13ms
30 timing idealTree:userRequests Completed in 0ms
31 silly idealTree buildDeps
32 timing idealTree:#root Completed in 0ms
33 timing idealTree:buildDeps Completed in 0ms
34 timing idealTree:fixDepFlags Completed in 0ms
35 timing idealTree Completed in 15ms
36 timing arborist:ctor Completed in 0ms
37 timing reify:loadTrees Completed in 21ms
38 timing reify:diffTrees Completed in 2ms
39 silly reify moves {}
40 timing reify:retireShallow Completed in 0ms
41 timing reify:createSparse Completed in 0ms
42 timing reify:loadBundles Completed in 0ms
43 silly audit bulk request {
43 silly audit   'default-shell': [ '2.2.0' ],
43 silly audit   execa: [ '5.1.1' ],
43 silly audit   'cross-spawn': [ '7.0.3' ],
43 silly audit   'is-stream': [ '2.0.1' ],
43 silly audit   'path-key': [ '3.1.1' ],
43 silly audit   'shebang-command': [ '2.0.0' ],
43 silly audit   'shebang-regex': [ '3.0.0' ],
43 silly audit   which: [ '2.0.2' ],
43 silly audit   expo: [ '1.0.0' ],
43 silly audit   'fix-path': [ '4.0.0' ],
43 silly audit   'get-stream': [ '6.0.1' ],
43 silly audit   'human-signals': [ '2.1.0' ],
43 silly audit   isexe: [ '2.0.0' ],
43 silly audit   'merge-stream': [ '2.0.0' ],
43 silly audit   'mimic-fn': [ '2.1.0' ],
43 silly audit   'npm-run-path': [ '4.0.1' ],
43 silly audit   onetime: [ '5.1.2' ],
43 silly audit   'shell-env': [ '4.0.1' ],
43 silly audit   'shell-path': [ '3.0.0' ],
43 silly audit   'signal-exit': [ '3.0.7' ],
43 silly audit   'strip-ansi': [ '7.0.1' ],
43 silly audit   'ansi-regex': [ '6.0.1' ],
43 silly audit   'strip-final-newline': [ '2.0.0' ],
43 silly audit   yarn: [ '1.22.17' ]
43 silly audit }
44 timing reify:unpack Completed in 1ms
45 timing reify:unretire Completed in 0ms
46 timing build:queue Completed in 0ms
47 timing build:deps Completed in 0ms
48 timing build Completed in 0ms
49 timing reify:build Completed in 1ms
50 timing reify:trash Completed in 0ms
51 timing reify:save Completed in 3ms
52 http fetch POST 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/-/npm/v1/security/advisories/bulk 241ms
53 timing auditReport:getReport Completed in 242ms
54 silly audit report {}
55 timing auditReport:init Completed in 0ms
56 timing reify:audit Completed in 242ms
57 timing reify Completed in 269ms
58 timing command:install Completed in 277ms
59 timing command:run-script Completed in 1ms
60 timing command:test Completed in 4ms
61 timing command:install-test Completed in 282ms
62 verbose stack Error: Missing script: "test"
62 verbose stack
62 verbose stack To see a list of scripts, run:
62 verbose stack   npm run
62 verbose stack     at RunScript.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/commands/run-script.js:95:13)
62 verbose stack     at async module.exports (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cli.js:66:5)
63 verbose cwd /Users/main
64 verbose Darwin 21.2.0
65 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install-test"
66 verbose node v16.14.0
67 verbose npm  v8.3.1
68 error Missing script: "test"
68 error
68 error To see a list of scripts, run:
68 error   npm run
69 verbose exit 1
70 timing npm Completed in 398ms
71 verbose code 1
72 error A complete log of this run can be found in:
72 error     /Users/main/.npm/_logs/2022-02-21T14_13_35_935Z-debug-0.log
```

•**npm expo start —-version** works but, **npm expo start** claims that “expo” is an unknown command, which seems odd because how can expo as a command be conditionally available as a command?

•I have also tested this with yarn to confirm the same problem occurs regardless of what package is installed.

Echo $PATH is:

```
/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin/Users/main/.npm-global/bin
```

What can I do to fix this?